# Why did my external IP stop working from within my network, when it worked before?

Tags: networking, router, nat

I host a website from a computer in my home network. For the past year or so, I could connect to it with the external IP/domain name from within the network. Now (after no changes) I can only use the external IP/domain name outside of the network. Most answers on this topic suggest that the router does not support NAT loopback/hairpin NAT, but if that was the case it would never have worked at all, right?

I am using the Xfinity supplied XB6-T gateway.

Comment: Then you can deduce *something* really *changed*, this is undisputable. This is the only logical explanation on why the behaviour was changed. Somebody certainly did something with the device. If it wasn't you, it was somebody else. Probably your provider updated the firmware or "hardeded" the configuration. One or the other, without knowing exactly how it is configured now, we won't be able to help.

Comment: Does the gateway report its own IP address as matching the one visible externally?

Comment: @user1686 Yes it does, the "WAN IP Address" in the router details matches the IP address visible externally (from WhatIsMyIP etc...) as well as the A record for the DNS settings on my domain

Comment: Reset the gateway to factory defaults - It will then work again.